# Why is a javascript (fluidvids.js) only working when loaded *after* a video embed?

Tags: javascript, html, jekyll, fluid-layout, github-pages

I am unable to get [fluidsvids.js](https://github.com/toddmotto/fluidvids) to work on my github pages-hosted website (running on [Poole](http://www.getpoole.com)/[Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com)) when the fluidvids.js code is inserted *before* the video embeds.

However, when inserting the code *after* the video embeds, the videos resize to the layout thanks to fluidvids.js. **Why is that?**

---

I extracted the entire [fluidvids zip](https://github.com/toddmotto/fluidvids/archive/master.zip) file into [`/public/js/fluidvids`](https://github.com/fredrikaverpil/fredrikaverpil.github.io/tree/master/public/js/fluidvids).

In my `_includes` folder, I created an html file, [`fluidvids.html`](https://github.com/fredrikaverpil/fredrikaverpil.github.io/blob/master/_includes/fluidvids.html):

```
<!-- fluidvids.js -->
<script src="{{ site.baseurl }}public/js/fluidvids/dist/fluidvids.js"></script>
<script>
fluidvids.init({
  selector: ['iframe'],
  players: ['www.youtube.com', 'player.vimeo.com']
});
</script>
```

And in my [`default.html`](https://github.com/fredrikaverpil/fredrikaverpil.github.io/blob/master/_layouts/default.html) layout, I inserted `{% include fluidvids.html %}`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

  {% include head.html %}
  {% include google_analytics.html %}

  <body>
    {% include fluidvids.html %}
    {% include sidebar.html %}

    <div class="content container">
      {{ content }}
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Finally, I embedded two videos for testing in a post; [`2007-02-10-Island-of-Lost-Souls.md`](https://github.com/fredrikaverpil/fredrikaverpil.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2007-02-10-Island-of-Lost-Souls.md):

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/9685584" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZdyzjKDWpYU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

However, the videos did not resize with the layout until I placed the include *after* the blog post content, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

  {% include head.html %}
  {% include google_analytics.html %}

  <body>
    {% include sidebar.html %}

    <div class="content container">
      {{ content }}
      {% include fluidvids.html %}
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Why is that?**

[Here's](http://fredrikaverpil.github.io/2007/02/10/Island-of-Lost-Souls/) the rendered post, when fluidvid.js is loaded *after* the blog post contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're not waiting for document ready (onload) before calling fluidvids.init. If that script block is before your video elements you need to wait for document onload event, otherwise the initialization will (silently?) fail, since the selectors won't return any element as the browser hasn't had a chance to process their markup yet. 
So either bind to the onload event and then run the fluidvids initialization, or include the script block after the elements in question.

BTW, best practices say script blocks are to be included at the end of the body element.